# Uncaught exceptions when passing promises into pg promise batch transaction

Tags: javascript, express, promise, pg-promise

I'm working on learning express and pg promise and have come across an issue that I suspect is a result from my not as firm as it should be grasp of promises.

Basically I have written some functions that I can use to query the database. I also have a function to use when handling any rejections. Those functions work perfectly when they are used alone (whether they succeed or throw an exception).

Here is a sample example:

```
const addToColumn = (tableName, columnName, entryId, amountToAdd) => {
    return db.one('UPDATE ${table:name} SET ${column:name} = ${column:name} + ${amount:csv} WHERE id = ${id:csv} RETURNING *', {
        table: tableName,
        column: columnName,
        amount: amountToAdd,
        id: entryId
    }).catch(err => handleQueryErr(err));
};
```

The functions also work perfectly when passed into a batch transaction manually like this:

```
const transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds =  async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        req.updatedEnvelopes = await db.tx(t => {
            return t.batch([
                addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeFromId, -req.transferBudget),
                addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeToId, req.transferBudget)
            ]);
        }).catch(err => handleTransactionErr(err));
        next();
    }catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
};
```

But then when I try to call this function in the middleware instead, if there is any database error (such as the database not running), then the server crashes with an uncaught excemption:

```
const batchQuery = (queryArray) => {
    return db.tx(t => {
        return t.batch(queryArray);
    }).catch(err => handleTransactionErr(err));
};


const transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds =  async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        req.updatedEnvelopes = await batchQuery([
            addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeToId, -req.transferBudget),
            addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeToId, req.transferBudget)
        ])
        next();
    }catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
};
```

From what I can tell the rejection never get's caught anywhere and has something to do with passing the array of promises into the function. If the query succeeds then the batchQuery function works. It only fails when it fails to catch a database error. Any ideas? If it's not possible to work I can just write out the whole batchQuery every time I need it, but I would still like to understand why it isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here it is with the callback, it's now catching all errors as expected and works perfectly if everything succeeds. It also catches the error if one of the queries fails, but unfortunately it doesn't rollback when using the batchQuery function.  I thought batch was supposed to take an array of promises to resolve, but the current method doesn't seem to quite work as I anticipated.

```
const transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds =  async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
    req.updatedEnvelopes = await batchQuery(() => 
        [
            addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeFromId, -req.transferBudget),
            addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeToId, req.transferBudget)
        ]);  
        next();
    }catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
};
```

Edit 2:
I have it working now using functions, but not quite with the batchQuery function. I now pass t as an optional argument into addToColumn and it works great.

```
const addToColumn = (tableName, columnName, entryId, amountToAdd, t) => {
    let context = t;
    if(context === undefined){
        context = db;
    }
    return context.one('UPDATE ${table:name} SET ${column:name} = ${column:name} + ${amount:csv} WHERE id = ${id:csv} RETURNING *', {
        table: tableName,
        column: columnName,
        amount: amountToAdd,
        id: entryId
    }).catch(err => handleQueryErr(err));
};

const transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        req.updatedEnvelopes = await db.tx(t => {
            return t.batch([
                addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeFromId, -req.transferBudget, t),
                addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeToId, req.transferBudget, t)
            ])
        }).catch(err => handleTransactionErr(err));
        next();
    }catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that your `addToColumn()` calls are not actually happening in the transaction. They are executed *before* their results are passed into `batchQuery`, but they need to be executed inside the `db.tx` callback. Pass a callback to `batchQuery` instead

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, you always give me the best answers! That's what I suspected was happening but couldn't quite figure out how to solve it. Passing it in as a callback isn't quite as clean and slick as an array, but it absolutely worked. Thanks again!

Comment: For starters, there is no transaction here. You are supposed to execute queries inside transaction against the `t` context that transaction gives you, not the root `db` object, which executes outside of transaction. And then I would remove all the local `catch` handlers, there should be just one, in your express handler/controller. The way it is at the moment, nothing looks obvious, but then you may not show everything, as your error handling is all over the place.

Comment: @vitaly-t Right I haven't been able to get it to revert if a query fails using this technique yet. I have even tried wrapping the addToColumn logic in tx/t/batch to no avail. Any idea how to achieve the idea of putting an array of functions into a predefined batch function? Error handling seems okay though, catches everything, custom messages, and pretty logical on the large scale.

Comment: It doesn't rollback because it takes an error to trigger the rollback, which you swallow within your local catch handler.

Comment: The error handling shouldn't be swollowing the err, it's just adding custom info to the err and then rethrowing it. I guess it could all be moved to the middleware though, but it is working since Bergi's suggestions. Also since I added the t to the args of addToColumn, it works as intended. The only thing that doesn't work is the rollback when using batchQuery, but I didn't know that batch is obsolete, thanks for that, definitely simplifies it and I'll just ditch the idea of a seprate batchQuery function since everything with my code above works fine and is simple enough after removing batch

Answer (score 2):

Your error-handling is all over the place, hence unpredictable transaction outcome. You need to streamline it, move error handling into one place...

```js
function addToColumn(tableName, columnName, entryId, amountToAdd, t) {
    return (t || db).one('UPDATE ${table:name} SET ${column:name} = ${column:name} + ${amount:csv} WHERE id = ${id:csv} RETURNING *', {
        table: tableName,
        column: columnName,
        amount: amountToAdd,
        id: entryId
    });
};

async function transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const res = await db.tx(async t => {
            const one = await addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeFromId, -req.transferBudget, t);
            const two = await addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', req.envelopeToId, req.transferBudget, t);
            return {one, two};
        });
        // res = {one, two};
        next();
    } catch(err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
```

Also, [batch](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Task.html#batch) is now obsolete, you do not need to use it at all.

Comment: Nice, didn't know batch is obsolete, I'll remove that and ditch the idea of the batchQuery function since the logic is pretty straightforward now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

This should prevent the server from crashing due to an uncaught exception

```
const transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    req.test = await batchQuery([
        addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', 100, req.toId).catch(err => handleQueryErr(err)),
        addToColumn('envelopes', 'budget', 100, req.fromId).catch(err => handleQueryErr(err))
    ])
    next();
} catch (err) {
    next(err);
}};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I was trying something along those lines but unfortunately it doesn't work either. addToColumn also has the error handling inside it, which also doesn't work. By logging to the console I can see that it is entering the handleQueryErr function properly (which re-throws the err + a custom message), but then the error is not being caught by the final catch block of transferEnvelopeBudgetByIds .